# Not able to upgrade ubuntu version 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, 15.10

First of all I am trying to upgrade php version 7.0 to 7.1 in ubuntu 15.10 and [I asked the question but community closed my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148235/not-able-to-upgrade-php-version-7-0-to-7-1) and asked me upgrade ubunuu version so I asked this new question.

**I think this is not duplicate question, as I tried all of the online solution but nothing worked so please check my output.**

I am using Ubuntu version `15.10`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid partner
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ stable main # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
```

and whenever I am trying to update it gives me below output,

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                             
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                                                                      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                          
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                                       
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease                                                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                                         
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease                                             
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable InRelease                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                                                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                                                               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                     
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                                      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                      
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial Release.gpg
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources                                                                             
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Sources                                                                           
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources                                                                               
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources                                                                           
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources                                                                                
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources                                                                          
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources                                                                            
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Sources                                                                          
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial Release                                                                                             
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable Release                                                                                             
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial/main Translation-en_IN                                                                              
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com xenial/main Translation-en                                                                                 
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                                                                              
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                                 
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I followed all of the links to change the ***/etc/apt/sources.list*** to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` from `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` but nothing helps me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) You need to also remove the lines in your sources.list from Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid) because you are upgrading from 15.10, not 15.04.

Comment: This is not duplicate please see my error now @karel , I don't know why my question is suggesting close ?

Comment: What command are you trying to release-upgrade with?  Did you just modify your sources yourself (with a search/replace) and then try and dist-upgrade?  Ubuntu doesn't release-upgrade that way.

Comment: Please see my edit @Kulfy , I added the sources.list

Comment: Yes, I modified the source by myself as I got some article that I need to change the URL with archive.ubuntu.com to old.release.ubuntu.com @guiverc

Comment: Yes, I am please see my edit I added the output @Kulfy

Comment: Could you please explain how I can upgrade If I am doing wrong @guiverc

Comment: Upgrading from 15.10 (or 14.04 LTS) to 16.04 is covered in the 16.04 release notes - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes   Note:  it was tested using 16.04 as it was at release 2016, and was tested to continue to work in 14.04 LTS's lifespan, but 15.10 updates stopped long ago and thus your ~3 year past EOL may have added issues, so please consider @Kulfy's advice (removing 3rd party..)

Comment: Thank you so much @Kulfy just upgraded the version to 16.04 and now I am planning to upgrade it to 18.10, please add the answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: also thanks a to @guiverc for your time and help :)

Comment: @keyur I recommend you to stick to LTS version such as 16.04 and 18.04 instead of non-LTS release 18.10 to avoid upgarding every six months at least. 18.10 will go EOL next month.

Comment: ok, thanks I will keep in mind and for the 18.04  I need to follow the same step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository information here looks malformed. It contains repository information of vivid (15.04), wily (15.10) and xenial (16.04). Since you are using Wily Werewolf (15.10), you need to restore default repository information of wily. Moreover wily is now EOL, so old-releases would work instead of typical archives. To restore default repository information for Wily (old-releases) use either of the two methods:

- Remove old sources.list

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

  Recreate sources.list. I've pasted repository information (old-releases) [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y26ZXgjTxs/) for convenience. Copy and paste repository information from there using

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

  Save and Exit.

**OR**

- Open **Software and Updates** app, select components and click on save/reload. You might get `failed to fetch repository information` and that's quite obvious. Click **OK** and run

  ```
  sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

Now, ensure all packages are up-to-date before upgrading the system. For that run,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Also, before upgrading system to  a newer release, considering disabling all 3rd party PPA and removing all packages installed from that.